# Resetting a QML StackView to initial state

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML `StackView` which during the application has many components being pushed to it. What I would like to do is actually reset the `StackView`to its initial state at some point during the application. The StackView is defined as:

```
StackView {
    id: soemID
    initialItem: myItem
}
```

As the application goes on things get pushed and popped. I looked for some convenient way to reset this to only hold the initial item but could not find it. Is the only way to do this would be to successively pop the items till only one item remains?

Comment: What about [StackView.clear()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html#clear-method)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
soemID.pop(null)
```

should do the trick.
From StackView documentation:

> Item pop(Item item = undefined)
>
> If item is null, all items down to (but not including) the first item
>   will be popped. If not specified, only the current item will be
>   popped....

Comment: This is better than my previous solution.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by the comment, clearing the stack and then pushing the initial item did the trick.

```
soemID.clear()
soemID.push(soemID.initialItem)
```

Comment: @luco, really? did you try it?

Comment: @fralbo This was a while ago so I do not remember but if I commented here it must have worked.

Comment: @luco According to my tests after a `stack.clear()` any `stack.push()` fails with undefined stack error... So the solution is effectively to call `stack.pop(null)`.